# Set NSWindow as full width and height not working

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode7, nswindow

I'm using a simple app boilerplate here:
https://github.com/hiven/WebViewFinagler

It just opens google on load. I've compiled it and it works fine but it opens in a very small window (480 x480). I can see a side menu in x-code but it only allows me to set the position of the window and the size of the window in pixels.

However, I want this to take up the whole screen (not fullscreen) - but I also don't want to hardcode the resolution of my mac into it because I want it to work on laptops with different screen resolutions.

It won't let me put in 100% in the width and height, so how do I make this app open and take up the full available screen area?

In my code I have this, but it doesn't work, the app just starts small in the bottom corner:

MDAppDelegate.m

```
#import "MDAppDelegate.h"
#import <WebKit/WebKit.h>


@implementation MDAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSWindow* myWindow; //Your window object to maximize
    [myWindow setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] display:YES];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.com/"]];
    [self.webView.mainFrame loadRequest:request];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you added would likely crash or do nothing:

```
NSWindow* myWindow; // uninitialized pointer refers to nothing (nil)
[myWindow setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] display:YES];
```

The last line sends a message to `myWindow`, which is `nil`, so the messages are just ignored.

There's a couple of different things you could do. The issue you were having is that you didn't get a reference to the actual window you wanted to maximize, which is defined as `window` in the header file:

```
@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;
```

So, you could theoretically change your code to the following and it would work:

```
NSWindow* myWindow = self.window;
[myWindow setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] display:YES];
```

However, it would make more sense to get rid of that first line, and just use `self.window` directly:

```
[self.window setFrame:[[NSScreen mainScreen] visibleFrame] display:YES];
```

That said, we can really simplify it even further, since `NSWindow` already has a method that will maximize the window to take up the whole screen: [`performZoom:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWindow/performZoom:).

```
[self.window performZoom:nil];
```

You can have the window's size and dimensions saved automatically upon quit and relaunch by setting an autosave name in Interface Builder for the window. (I think I forgot to add one to that sample code project).

Comment: [self.window performZoom:nil]; worked perfectly, thank you so much for explaining it.